# How to Write JPA FindBy Query for AND and OR conditions

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a JPA query from JPA findBy method

```
select * from somTable where Col1 =1
    and (col2 > 0 or col2 = 0)
    and (col3 > 0 or col3 = 0)
    and (col4 >0 or col4 =0)
    and (col5 >0 or col5 =0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve it

- The `Spring Data JPA` way, using [@Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) and [Named Parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters):

  ```
  public interface SomeTableRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeTable, Long> {   
      @Query("SELECT t FROM SomeTable t WHERE t.col1 = :col1 AND t.col2 >= :col2 AND t.col3 >= :col3")
      List<SomeTable> findAllByCol(@Param("col1") int col1, @Param("col2") int col2, @Param("col3") int col3);
  }
  ```
- The `JPA` way, using `JPA Criteria Queries`:

  ```
  @Repository
  @Transactional
  public class SomeTableJpaRepository {

      @PersistenceContext
      EntityManager entityManager;

      public List<SomeTable> findAll(int col1, int col2, int col3, int col4, int col5) {
          CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
          CriteriaQuery<SomeTable> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(SomeTable.class);
          Root<SomeTable> itemRoot = criteriaQuery.from(SomeTable.class);

          List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

          Predicate predicateCol1
                = criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("col1"), col1);
          predicates.add(predicateCol1);

          Predicate predicateCol2
                = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(itemRoot.get("col2"), col2);
          predicates.add(predicateCol2);

          Predicate predicateCol3
                = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(itemRoot.get("col3"), col3);
          predicates.add(predicateCol3);

          // ...
          criteriaQuery.select(itemRoot).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

          return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
      }
  }
  ```